# Question about keeping a reference to a unique_ptr in another class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

Recently, I decided that it was time that I should dig into smart pointers. I read about the different kinds (unique, shared, weak), but I'm not sure about one thing.

Let say that I have a class `Player` and a `GameMap` class. The content of those classes are irrelevant for the next part. I also have an `Engine` class, that represents the object that will hold the main components of my game, like this:

```
class Engine {
public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Player> m_player;
    std::unique_ptr>GameMap> m_gamemap;
};
```

These are the only instances of the player and game map that will be created, and the `Engine` owns them, and should be responsible for their allocation and deletion. So, a `unique_ptr` seems to be the good choice here.

Now, I would like to keep a simple reference to `m_player` in my `GameMap` class, since it would be easier for me than passing the `m_player` to each function that need it.

My question is: **is using a raw pointer (obtained through the `get()` method) in the `GameMap` class the best way to keep a reference to the original `unique_ptr` located in the `Engine` class?** I think that I can't use another `unique_ptr` pointing to the original one, since it would not be logical regarding to the use case of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yes a non-owning raw pointer of `Player*` within `GameMap` would be perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: *So, a unique_ptr seems to be the good choice here.* Only if you need a pointer to begin with. Maybe you do, but it's not clear from your example.

Comment: Yes indeed, I did not talk about the whole project, but I need to make sure that I really need to use a pointer. It's an old project that I'm refactoring, and maybe I can actually use some references instead of pointers, which would be way better.

Comment: I've marked up the sentence with how I've interpreted it, "Now, I would like to keep a simple reference to m_player in my GameMap class so I can treat it as a global and break encapsulation and employ high-coupling and low-cohesion and practically impossible to unit test and a legacy maintenance nightmare, since it would be easier for me than passing the m_player to each function that need it."

Answer (score 0):

I think that using of raw pointer isn't the best way. For example, better way is use shared_ptr for player and gamemap. And adds weak_ptr of player into gamemap.

Comment: Alright, I must admit that I'm not really familiar with weak pointers yet. If I understood correctly, it will keep a reference to the object if it's still alive? It seems to be a good choice indeed, since the GameMap would be managed by the Engine and has no business in managing the Player.

Comment: @Coulis `weak_ptr` is useful if the reference counted object (via `shared_ptr`) can be destroyed and you need to find out before you try to use it.  If you have a definite owner and known lifetime then `sharded_ptr` /  `weak_ptr` is usually not required.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! It's a lot clearer for me now :)